# Xamarin iOS 64bit binding fails on device but not simulator

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin, 64-bit

I have an ad sdk native library that has worked well for me before the 64-bit change. It's here: https://github.com/bbhsu2/XamarinAdMarvelBinding.

My problem is that I now have the following code which loads the ad in the iOS simulator, but does not run in a real device:

```
public AGPAdMarvelAd(UIViewController viewController, CGRect frame) : base(frame)
{
    adMarvelView = AdMarvelView.CreateView(this);
    adMarvelView.GetAdWithNotification();
    AddSubview(adMarvelView);   
}
```

where AdMarvelView.CreateView() is defined as:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
[Protocol]
interface AdMarvelView
{
    [Static, Export("createAdMarvelViewWithDelegate:")]
    AdMarvelView CreateView(IAdMarvelDelegate del);
    ...
}
```

In the simulator, the adMarvelView object is created and the ad loads just fine. In a device, adMarvelView is null and the app crashes.

I also updated my libAdMarvelSDK.linkwith.cs file as follows:

```
using System;
using ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libAdMarvelSDK.a", LinkTarget.Simulator64 | LinkTarget.Arm64 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator,
SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]
```

Also, I can use the native library with no problem using Obj-C and Swift.

Comment: Can you add '-v -v -v -v' to the additional mtouch arguments and pastebin the build log after rebuilding the project?

Comment: build log: http://pastebin.com/eEBr2mpq

Comment: this is the application output, so it looks like the binding project is uploaded to the device: http://pastebin.com/UqVY8zXr

Comment: Does the app work on a 32-bit device? And can you verify that the native library includes arm64 code (`lipo -info /Users/bernardhsu/Desktop/repos/lactmed/lactmed/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libAdMarvelSDK.a`)?

Comment: the ads load on a 32 bit device. this is the lipo output:  

Architectures in the fat file: /Users/bernardhsu/Desktop/repos/lactmed/lactmed/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libAdMarvelSDK.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: That looks fine. Can you do `nm -arch all /Users/bernardhsu/Desktop/repos/lactmed/lactmed/bin/iPhone/Debug/lactmed.app/lactmed` and pastebin that? This is to confirm that the symbols for the library end up in the executable.

Comment: well I can't pastebin because it's too large and copy and paste to vim is taking too long so heres the file: http://1drv.ms/1AsptWr. I do see the plt_AdMarvelBinding_AdMarvelView_CreateView_AdMarvelBinding_IAdMarvelDelegate
0040c3d0 t symbol several times

Comment: This is strange, there is no obvious difference between the three (armv7, armv7s, arm64) architectures in the executable. But there is no `createAdMarvelViewWithDelegate:` selector either, so I'm not sure how this even works on 32-bit architectures. Can you do `nm -arch all /Users/bernardhsu/Desktop/repos/lactmed/lactmed/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libAdMarvelSDK.a` to see what the library contains?

Comment: here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bbhsu2/0a33c55c11dbbef18878/raw/gistfile1.txt

Comment: on the SDK docs here https://support.admarvel.com/display/AMS/iOS+SDK+Integration+Guide it says "When running on 64bit supported iOS devices, 64bit slices of the AdMarvel SDK libraries are loaded at run time. If your combination includes any non 64bit supported 3rd party SDKs, these SDKs will not work as there are no 64bit slices present." I am scratching my head on this whole issue.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge i was reading this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4685/embedding-dylib-i-give-up and I need to link libsqlite3.dylib, libstdc++.dylib and lib.dylib. can you help?

Comment: Try changing to `SmartLink = false` in your LinkWith attribute.